# meaning of "It's really owning it"

Tags: meaning

[An American tutorial says](https://youtu.be/FStyKn4V8cE?t=114)

> Rhythm is the real deal. Its the
>   feel of the language. **It's really owning it** once you start using American rhythm.

I understand the tutor is emphasizing the importance of rhythm. I don't understand the meaning of "It's really owning it". What does first and second "it" refer to there?

Answer (score 0):

Owning it here means "Doing really well to the point of demonstrating complete mastery".  When you own a skill, you aren't just able to copy the ability, instead you take it into yourself, make it your own unique ability based on the original, and then are able to improve upon that original by adding your own experience and style.

It also comes close to the slang, "being owned / pwnd" which honestly was close to how I read the original statement.  Being owned of course is having someone so utterly defeat you in an activity that they have demonstrated the above mentioned mastery in regards to you.  It is used often on the internet, but is quite rude if you think about it much.

To answer the actual questions:
The first it refers to the action of being able to use "American rhythm" 
The second it refers the action of owning / mastering that skill.

(Being able to use) American Rhythm in this way is really (showing true master of the skill.)"

Comment: I've got the point of the first paragraph in you answer, "to demonstrate mastery well", thank you! I don't really understand the relationship between "being owned" and "owning it". Would you please explain a little bit more on that?

Comment: That is some internet slang that is quite prevalent in gaming groups.  Short answer, being owned == being utterly defeated :)